# How can I sanitize and convert characters to HTML entities while preserving HTML tags (Javascript/NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wanting to accept rich input from a WYSIWYG editor, however, I want to convert all special characters to HTML entities while still keeping the HTML tags.

I am wanting to output the same rich text as was inputed. However, what if someone includes a < or > character as part of their text? I don't want that to be mistaken as a beginning or ending HTML tag.

Comment: Why do you think, that a WYSIWYG editor would not take care of this?

Comment: @Thomas I would like to take care of this on the backend and not rely solely on the wysiwyg on the frontend.

Comment: Not sure I follow, html tags are precisely the kind of things you you want to convert to html entities... Unless you are saying you want to sanitize out style and script tags...

Comment: If you source markup, has a wrapper container, you could extract it's children and sanitize those...

Comment: just add https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify and https://web.dev/trusted-types/

Comment: Was there any other aspects of your post which remain unaddressed?

Comment: Thanks man. I decided to go with sanitize-html, which works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to escape valid-html characters, so that they will be interpreted as normal text instead of HTML.

Strictly speaking, escaping valid HTML just means replacing valid characters with their respective *numeric character reference* (#0000;)

There are lots of libraries which specifically do this process of escaping & sanitisation, and you should choose one which best fits your language, use case and framework.

As a reference, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML):

- `&amp;` → & (ampersand, U+0026)
- `&lt;` → < (less-than sign, U+003C)
- `&gt;` → > (greater-than sign, U+003E)
- `&quot;` → " (quotation mark, U+0022)
- `&apos;` → ' (apostrophe, U+0027)

Comment: I want to keep the HTML tags as they are. I just want to sanitize the text content by converting those characters to html entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the client side implications of later rendering user submitted html, or the Server Side implications, or that code may be executed, server side as some point, than I guess you could simply Sanitize, Validate and Escape the content then base64 encode it wholesale, server side.

Honestly, this is one very good reason, to leverage markdown.

To be clear, you want to ensure you consider your sanitization/verification/escaping concerns both Client-Side and Server-Side.

This [article](https://www.we45.com/blog/preventing-xss-with-base64-encoding-the-false-sense-of-web-application-security) goes into things a bit, and explains two types of XSS:

> In a reflected XSS attack, the attack is in the request itself
> (frequently the URL) and the vulnerability occurs when the server
> inserts the attack in the response verbatim or incorrectly escaped or
> sanitized. The victim triggers the attack by browsing to a malicious
> URL created by the attacker.

> In a stored XSS attack, the attacker stores the attack in the
> application (e.g., in a snippet) and the victim triggers the attack by
> browsing to a page on the server that renders the attack, by not
> properly escaping or sanitizing the stored data.

and does a decent job covering the process and importance of Sanitizing, Input Validation and Escaping.

#### Additional Resources:

Client Side:

- checkout [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks) to get started.
- [Cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) for XSS prevention

Server Side:

- If you are going to be storing this content, on the filesystem, where it 'could' ever be `included` or `required`, you need to ensure it is stored in a non-executable form.
- Stored in a Database, after being base64 encoded, could work.

Comment: You could use any number of libraries to encode the content, but you will still need to escape the content in every domain the data/content gets sent through. Client Side, Network, Server Side ( Language ), Server Side Persistence ( such as DB, FS etc ), and then again on the way back out.